# fabric chaincode invocation arguments usage

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

When in invoking a chaincode, what is the correct way of selecting the method you wish to invoke, for example, the following commands works and produce same results:

`peer chaincode invoke -n basic_go -C mychannel -c '{"function":"GetAllAssets","Args":[]}'`

`peer chaincode invoke -n basic_go -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["GetAllAssets"]}'`

You notice the first one names the function within the **function** property, the second invocation, uses the first argument of the **Args** array to do so.

For **GetAllAssets** works, but for **CreateAsset** for instance, it doesn't. You can only invoke it using the latter approach. I'm testing with https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go

I have not been able to find any clarification in the docs regarding this matter. Should the method be call separately as a property **function**, or as a first argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in my system and both methods are actually working for all chaincode invokes and queries. [This](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/ba7e92358b182995fb1cbea3b0c5c31361321d72/internal/peer/chaincode/common.go#L362) is the part of the source code where the function and args are read. They are considering both cases there.

Comment: I think you are correct. However while testing I found that the InitLedger function didn't fail (return 200) but did nothing unless I specified both peers with `--peerAddresses --tlsRootCertFiles` params. I guess it has something to do with my local config. In the docs, it's only passing the orderer.